# Django passing a string in url

Tags: python, regex, django, python-2.7

I want to pass a string, in the url, and then catch in in the view

```
<a href="{% url 'dolgozo:dolgozo-detail' orderby=nev %} ">
```

I want to pass "nev" string.

```
url(r'^orderby=(?P<nev>.+)$', login_required(DolgozokListView.as_view(template_name="DolgozoKarbantart/DolgozokList.html")), name='dolgozo-detail'),
```

What is the regex for this, and how can i catch it in the view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not try the simple one...

**HTML**

```
<a href="{% url 'dolgozo:dolgozo-detail' %}/?orderby={{ nev }}">
```

**URL**

```
url(r'^orderby/$', login_required(DolgozokListView.as_view(template_name="DolgozoKarbantart/DolgozokList.html")), name='dolgozo-detail'),
```

And in the view simply get the `orderby` using `GET`

```
orderby = request.GET.get('orderby')
```

Comment: Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:58487/dolgozo/orderby/?orderby=
Using the URLconf defined in MINY_Django.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^$ [name='login']
^logout/$ [name='logout']
^index/$ [name='index']
^dolgozo/ ^orderby=(?P<nev>.+)$ [name='dolgozo-detail']
^dolgozo/ ^orderby$ [name='dolgozo-detail']
^dolgozo/ ^update/(?P<pk>\d+)$ [name='dolgozo-update']
^dolgozo/ ^create/$ [name='dolgozo-create']
^dolgozo/ ^delete/(?P<pk>\d+)$ [name='dolgozo-delete']
^felhasznalo/
^dolgozomunkakor/
^munkaidoadat/
^munkakor/

Comment: There is an error with URL... I updated that pls check now

Comment: it's the same, with double slashes : http://localhost:62003/dolgozo/orderby//?orderby=

Comment: I've figured it out. You dont need that url,and everything is fine.

Answer (score 2):

html, no need for `/` before `?`

```
<a href="{% url 'dolgozo:dolgozo-detail' %}?orderby={{ nev }}">
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^orderby/$', login_required(DolgozokListView.as_view(template_name="DolgozoKarbantart/DolgozokList.html")), name='dolgozo-detail'),
```

views.py

```
orderby = request.GET.get('orderby')
```